# Symfony 4 Collections form err: Unable to guess

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I acted according to the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html, I need to add a common page for editing all records of one entity, and also advised to use the "collection of forms". There were errors like "`add use ORM`" and similar, now came across a ***`ERROR`***. ***`Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "abilityHolder".`*** Google does not say anything, it shows only the old information from symfony2, and I use flex, below I'll attach the files that relate to my task

***src/Ability.php*** - my main entity for getting and writing Abilitys

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AbilityRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="Ability")
 */
class Ability
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="idItem")
     */
    private $idItem;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", name="reloadTime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $reloadTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", name="durationTime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $durationTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="idAbilityType")
     */
    private $idAbilityType;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true, name="dateCreated")
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true, name="dateChange")
     */
    private $dateChange;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, name="lastAuthor")
     */
    private $lastAuthor;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(?int $id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdItem(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idItem;
    }

    public function setIdItem(int $idItem): self
    {
        $this->idItem = $idItem;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(?string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getReloadTime(): ?float
    {
        return $this->reloadTime;
    }

    public function setReloadTime(?float $reloadTime): self
    {
        $this->reloadTime = $reloadTime;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDurationTime(): ?float
    {
        return $this->durationTime;
    }

    public function setDurationTime(?float $durationTime): self
    {
        $this->durationTime = $durationTime;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateCreated(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    public function setDateCreated(\DateTimeInterface $dateCreated): self
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuthor(): ?string
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function setAuthor(string $author): self
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateChange(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateChange;
    }

    public function setDateChange(\DateTimeInterface $dateChange): self
    {
        $this->dateChange = $dateChange;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastAuthor(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastAuthor;
    }

    public function setLastAuthor(string $lastAuthor): self
    {
        $this->lastAuthor = $lastAuthor;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdAbilityType(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idAbilityType;
    }

    public function setIdAbilityType(int $idAbilityType): self
    {
        $this->idAbilityType = $idAbilityType;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

***src/AbilityHolder.php*** - Collections form entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="AbilityHolder")
 */

class AbilityHolder
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    protected $abilitys;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->abilitys = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getAbilitys()
    {
        return $this->abilitys;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

***Form/AbilityType.php*** form from Ability

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Ability;
use App\Entity\Item;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use App\Repository\AbilityTypeRepository;
use App\Repository\ItemRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class AbilityType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $abilityTypeRepository;
    protected $itemRepository;

    public function __construct(AbilityTypeRepository $abilityTypeRepository, ItemRepository $itemRepository){
        $this->abilityTypeRepository = $abilityTypeRepository;
        $this->itemRepository = $itemRepository;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $abilitys = $this->abilityTypeRepository->findAll();
        $items = $this->itemRepository->findAll();
        foreach ($abilitys as $ability) {
            $abilityCode[] = $ability->getCode();
            $abilityId[] = $ability->getId();
        }
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $itemCode[] = $item->getCode();
            $itemId[] = $item->getId();
        }
        $abilityCodeId = array_combine($abilityCode, $abilityId); //склеивание ассоциативного массива из двух массивов
        $itemCodeId = array_combine($itemCode, $itemId); //склеивание ассоциативного массива из двух массивов
        ksort($abilityCodeId);
        ksort($itemCodeId);

        $builder
            ->add('idItem', ChoiceType::class, array( 'choices'  => $itemCodeId ))
            //->add('idItem', EntityType::class, ['class' => Item::class,'choice_label' => 'code','choice_value' => 'id',])
            ->add('code')
            ->add('reloadTime')
            ->add('durationTime')
            ->add('idAbilityType', ChoiceType::class, array( 'choices'  => $abilityCodeId ))
            // ->add('dateCreated',DateType::class)
            // ->add('author')
            // ->add('dateChange',DateType::class)
            // ->add('lastAuthor')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Ability::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

***Form/AbilityHolderType.php*** - form from Ability

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\AbilityHolder;
use App\Form\AbilityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class AbilityHolderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('abilitys', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => AbilityType::class,
            'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
            'allow_add' => true,
        ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => AbilityHolder::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

***Controller/AbilityHolderController.php***- form from AbilityHolder-collections form

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\AbilityHolder;
use App\Entity\Ability;
use App\Form\AbilityHolderType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use App\Controller\EntityManagerInterface;
use App\Repository\AbilityRepository;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;


/**
 * @Route("/ability-holder")
 * @ParamConverter (name ="abilityHolder", Class ="App\Entity\AbilityHolder") 
 */
class AbilityHolderController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/edit", name="ability_holder_edit", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, AbilityHolder $abilityHolder)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $originalAbilitys = new ArrayCollection();

        // Create an ArrayCollection of the current Tag objects in the database
        foreach ($abilityHolder->getAbilitys() as $ability) {
            $originalAbilitys->add($ability);
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(AbilityHolderType::class, $abilityHolder);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // remove the relationship between the tag and the Task
            foreach ($originalAbilitys as $ability) {
                if (false === $abilityHolder->getAbilitys()->contains($ability)) {
                    // remove the Task from the Tag
                    $tag->getTasks()->removeElement($abilityHolder);

                    // if it was a many-to-one relationship, remove the relationship like this
                    // $tag->setTask(null);

                    $entityManager->persist($ability);

                    // if you wanted to delete the Tag entirely, you can also do that
                    // $entityManager->remove($tag);
                }
            }

            $entityManager->persist($abilityHolder);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('ability_holder_edit');
        }
        var_dump($abilityHolder);

        return $this->render('ability/edit.holder.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="ability_new", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    /*public function new(Request $request)
    {
        $abilitys = new AbilityHolder();
        $ability1 = new Ability();
        $ability1->setIdItem('1');
        $ability1->setCode('code');
        $ability1->setReloadTime('1');
        $ability1->setDurationTime('1');
        $ability1->setIdAbilityType('1');

        // dummy code - this is here just so that the Ability has some tags
        // otherwise, this isn't an interesting example
        $abilitys->getAbilitys()->add($ability1);
        // end dummy code

        $form = $this->createForm(AbilityHolderType::class, $abilitys);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // ... maybe do some form processing, like saving the Ability and Tag objects
        }

        return $this->render('ability/new-holder.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/edit", name="ability_edit", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    /*public function edit(Request $request)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $originalAbilitys = new ArrayCollection();
    $abilityHolder = new AbilityHolder();

    // Create an ArrayCollection of the current Tag objects in the database
    foreach ($abilityHolder->getAbilitys() as $ability) {
        $originalAbilitys->add($ability);
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(AbilityHolderType::class, $abilityHolder);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        // remove the relationship between the ability and the Task
        foreach ($originalAbilitys as $ability) {
            if (false === $abilityHolder->getAbilitys()->contains($ability)) {
                // remove the Task from the Tag
                $ability->getAbilitys()->removeElement($abilityHolder);

                // if it was a many-to-one relationship, remove the relationship like this
                // $ability->setTask(null);

                $entityManager->persist($ability);

                // if you wanted to delete the Tag entirely, you can also do that
                // $entityManager->remove($ability);
            }
        }

        $entityManager->persist($abilityHolder);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

        return $this->render('ability/new-holder.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $editForm->createView(),
        ));

    // render some form template
}*/
}
```

***Twig Template***

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}

    {% for ability in form.abilitys %}
        <li>{{ form_row(ability.idItem) }}</li>
        <li>{{ form_row(ability.code) }}</li>
        <li>{{ form_row(ability.reloadTime) }}</li>
        <li>{{ form_row(ability.durationTime) }}</li>
        <li>{{ form_row(ability.idAbilityType) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Pnv.jpg)

***after adding / {id} to routing***

[image: after adding / {id} to routing]

***`[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Entity" in class App\Entity\AbilityHolder was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?`***
[image: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Entity" in class App\Entity\AbilityHolder was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?]

Comment: Wrongly tagged with `entity-framework` this tag is for .net

Comment: corrected, I apologize for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this has very little to do with forms. In fact, if I am not wrong, even if your would comment out the whole body of your action, it would still break.

The reason for this is the way you have set up your controller action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/ability-holder")
 * @ParamConverter (name ="abilityHolder", Class ="App\Entity\AbilityHolder") 
 */
class AbilityHolderController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/edit", name="ability_holder_edit", methods="GET|POST")
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, AbilityHolder $abilityHolder)
    {
```

By default, Symfony will try to inject services by using class name type hint, however, since you specified that `$abilityHolder` corresponds to param converter, it does try to find identifier within your URL (which is by default `id`). I do not see the `id` above, so you do need to specify it.

For example:

```
@Route("/edit/{id}", name="ability_holder_edit", methods="GET|POST")
```

Does the above work?

### UPDATE:

So, as I said in comment section below, `Doctrine` does not use constructor to create new instance of object. This leaves your object (as far as unmanaged members are concerned) in a half-initialized state.

One way to handle this would be to define a `postLoad` listener:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity 
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks 
 */
class AbilityHolder
{
...

    /** 
     * @ORM\PostLoad() 
     */
    public function onPostLoad()
    {
        $this->abilitys = new ArrayCollection();
    }    

...
}
```

Comment: added {id}, went routing, / ability-holder / edit / 1
now another error( Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ), attached to the question, while trying to decide what is wrong

Comment: Alright, you probably need to initialize ‘abilities’ to ‘array’ or ‘ArrayCollection’. As for the id, if you want to resolve the object from database via ParamConverter, you need to supply id. On one occasion, I wrote a ParamConverter which did not work with database but with session - but that is more of a edge case...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm in php novice, I need to initialize $abiltys as an array or ArrayCollection, that is, in the first case
$abiltys[] = ""; an empty array?
in the second
$abiltys = new ArrayCollection (); just a new empty object of the ArrayCollection class? I'll try if you do not have time to answer describe at once what happened, I understand that nothing will be stored in them, and foreach will overwrite everything that it finds

Comment: I'm confused because I do not have $abilitys =)

Comment: So, I took a peek above, and see that you actually have `$this->abilitys = new ArrayCollection();` in your constructor, which is good. Can you `var_dump($abilityHolder->getAbilitys()` just before the `foreach`?

Comment: var_dump($abilityHolder->getAbilitys()); // NULL

very strange!
why is that?

Comment: When the entity is initialised based on the data in the database, Doctrine will not call your entity constructors. And since the `$abilitys` property is not mapped it will simply be `null`. Is there a reason this property is not mapped?

Comment: hmmmmmmmm, even so I can not immediately understand, in theory everything should work, but I still do not understand why NULL

Comment: Ah, I see, this is expected. When `Doctrine` creates an object, it does not so via constructor, but via reflection. That means that your `$abilitys` will never get instantiated. A quick workaround would be to set it yourself. Let me try something and I'll update the answer...

Comment: that would make such a decision need to have a lot of experience, I will be very happy if something happens now!

Comment: I have updated the answer, however, I am currently not able to try it.

Comment: the error is gone! but, now a very strange situation has developed, if I run the foreach retype two var_dump and check
var_dump ($ abilityHolder-> onPostLoad ());
        var_dump ($ abilityHolder-> getAbilitys ());
then the answers to them are that the first NULL and the second object (Doctrine \ Common \ Collections \ ArrayCollection) # 1646 (1) {["elements": "Doctrine \ Common \ Collections \ ArrayCollection": private] => array (0) {}}
on the page is empty
if you remove all var_dump then it again appears Warning: Invalid argument supplied for forach ()

Comment: I did not add a new annotation, now I made and the error looks like [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Entity" in class App \ Entity \ AbilityHolder was never imported. Did you ever forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

that I need use, inside entity AbilityHolder use entity AbilityHolder? so it will not work

Comment: Yup, I forgot to add `ORM` namespace to those two annotations. I've updated the answer. One thing though, **you should never call onPostLoad()** by yourself - `Doctrine` will call that for you

Comment: I'm new to php and symfony 4 in general, maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Now, the doctrine tries to find a record with {id}, in the address bar I registered / ability-holder / edit / 1 and got the expected error
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1 FROM ability_holder t0 WHERE t0.id =?' with params ["1"]:

SQLSTATE [42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tank-admin.ability_holder' does not exist
since there is no such record
I create it myself, and what should I write in the $abilitys field?

Comment: I did not update the migration after adding
    / **
     * @ ORM \ Id ()
     * @ ORM \ GeneratedValue ()
     * @ ORM \ Column (type = "integer")
     * /
    private $ id;
now the query added the required field and it turned out that the error now looks different App \ Entity \ AbilityHolder object not found by the @ ParamConverter annotation.

Comment: I believe this is well beyond the scope of the question. You should really ask a new one :)

Comment: well, thank you very much, now the question has shifted from the place and I have material for further study, I can not suppose that I'm wrong?

Comment: You are most welcome. And, yes, you're right. I have suggested to split this in a separate question, merely so other fellow StackOverflowers could find the issue you have faced and could quickly learn from it :)